# Android countdown timer wont accept variable

Tags: android

i just started to learn creating android apps. I wanted to create a simple count down timer that takes a value from a edittext but countdown timer does not seem to run.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    countDownTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.countDownView);
    intervalTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.intervalText);

    findViewById(R.id.startBN).setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    int testInt = 30;
                    //countDownTxt.setText(intervalTxt.getText());
                    int interval = Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString());
                    Log.d("buttonpressed", "interval for countdown is " + interval);

                    cdt = new CountDownTimer(Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString()), 1000) {
                         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                             Log.d("counttimer1", "haha1");
                             countDownTxt.setText(""+ millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                         }

                         public void onFinish() {
                             cancel();
                         }
                      }.start();
                }
            }
    );
}
```

In particular, this program works only if i enter a numerical value such as 30000 in the 1st parameter of the CountDownTimer "cdt = new CountDownTimer(testInt, 1000)"

Can someone enlighten me please? Thank you!

Comment: So, is it working or not ? Can you show you logcat ? Why don't you reuse the value of your `interval` variable in `new CountDownTimer` ?

Comment: try `Long.parseLong(intervalTxt.getText().toString())` instead of `Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString())`

Comment: Hi, i have tried long as well. it does not work, the logcat if i use a variable it does not even go into onTick().

Answer (score 0):

"Doesn't work" how?  You should post the error message you're getting or other symptoms of "doesn't work."

---

What's probably happening is CountDownTimer accepts only long values as the first parameter of its constructor.  Not int values.

Change `int testInt = 30` to `long testLong = 10000.0f` and see what happens.

The first parameter means milliseconds, by the way, so "30" isn't really going to get you much in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

onTick() method is called in a separate Thread. But you don't have right to use `setText()` method outside the GUI Thread.
You must use a Handler object or `Activity.postOnUiThread()` method to execute something in the GUI Thread :

```
  cdt = new CountDownTimer(Integer.parseInt(intervalTxt.getText().toString()), 1000) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                           Log.d("counttimer1", "haha1");
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                   countDownTxt.setText("" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                            }
                        });
                           countDownTxt.setText(""+ millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        }

                        public void onFinish() {
                            cancel();
                        }
                     }.start();
```

For more informations, read http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Threads

Comment: Oh my.... it was a realy silly mistake on my side. That program works fine, i forgot to *1000 to the value of the edittext, which i believe result in the countdown executing too fast. Apologies and thanks everyone.